# JMockit - Mock REST client object

Tags: jmockit

I am using JMockit to do the unit testing. For one test cases, I want to create the mock of the third party REST client. The client object is of Apache Solr exposed REST service. When I record the test case using Expectations, this object does not get initialized and the test case fails due to NullPointerException.

The REST client is supposed to be created like this:

```
HttpSolrClient.Builder(solrUrl).withConnectionTimeout(10000).withSocketTimeout(60000).build()
```

To mock the client I did like this:

```
@Mocked SolrClient solrClient
```

I could not find, how can I create the mock object. What will be the correct way to create the client object?

Comment: So what was null? solrClient, output of the Builder, ... ? Btw, should not you not be mocking HttpSolrClient?

Comment: I figured it out, the issue got resolved by mocking SolrClient